# Jquery UI + Google Maps v3 API only loads after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

When you click on the tabs it should be load the map but it just load the content -except you refreshing the page. I almost try everything to fix it, but not succeed.

click here to check it

Comment: You have this message in console log `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null main.js:28`.

Comment: Please post the (relevant) code in your question (a link is useful, but might go away).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function initialize will be executed 1 second after `onload`, but when you click on a tab the `load`-event has already been fired and the map will not be initialized.

Remove this from your code(it forces the error as commented by  Anto Jurkovic ):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
window,
'load',
function(){
window.setTimeout(initialize, 1000);
});
```

and add this to `jqc_fnDone`:

```
if($('#map-canvas').length && !$('#map-canvas div').length){initialize();}
```

It will initialize the map when the map-container is present, but still empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest fix!**

On the link used to visit your page with the map, simply add **data-no-turbolink**

example:

```
<a href="/contactuspage" data-no-turbolink>Contact Us</a>
```

Problem Solved! I spent days trying to find an easy resolution to this problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure that your answer related to this question? I just noticed you have answered with two completely identical posts to 2 different questions.

Comment: yes, this is a possible solution for both issues I have answered.